# Why can we no longer address a commenter with the @name at start of comment?

Tags: bug

In a comment from the past-
@bob I don't wee why it is necessary to declare that var as you wrote it.

Now Stack Overflow scrapes off the leading @bob. It didn't used to. Isn't that the way that @bob is notified of a comment directed to him or her?

I want to make this clear- it happens EVEN if the @bob had previously commented as occurred in my comment only five minutes ago:

[Phonegap Cordova file move issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867365/phonegap-cordova-file-move-issues?noredirect=1#comment61817422_34867365)

Comment: *Now StackOverflow scrapes off the leading @bob.* As far as I know they haven't changed anything. Have you tried leaving another comment with the '@' at the beginning instead of after the username? I literally just got a comment notification 2 minutes ago because someone did '@BSMP'.

Comment: I have not noticed any change.  But one additional factor you are missing - if only 2 people (1 commenter and the OP) are commenting on the post, it will always be removed because it is assumed that you are replying to that person.  It has always done that.  Once a 3rd person joins, the `@` comments will no longer be stripped

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation